# Should one null check .NET EF Core DbContext properties before using

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), the generated `GetTodoItem(long id)` method I get differs from the one in the example. It includes a null check for `_context.TodoItems`. Now when writing my own controller methods and I am wondering if I should do these null checks or not.

Note that the TodoContext properties are not nullable, but are null instantiated (`= null!`). I am currently on .NET 6 but would like to know if the answer differs for .NET 8. Keep in mind I am new to .NET.

```cs
public class TodoContext : DbContext {
    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}
    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**Their generated code**

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
{
    var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);
    if (todoItem == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return todoItem;
}
```

**My generated code**

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
{
    if (_context.TodoItems == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);
    if (todoItem == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return todoItem;
}
```

I encountered 2 different ways of handling a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should one null check .NET EF Core DbContext properties before using

No, `DbSet` properties are managed by EF Core and if they for some reason will be null - there is something very-very bad happening and null check will not help.

As for the props - you have [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature enabled so check out the [Working with Nullable Reference Types: DbContext and DbSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset) you can change the sets to:

```
public class TodoContext : DbContext {
    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}
    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems => Set<TodoItem>();
}
```

So `= null!` does not bother the eye.